# Is transmitting PES(Packetised Elementary Stream) better or MPEG-TS in Live Streaming from mobile (IOS) to server

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am developing a Live Streaming application where mobile application (iOS/Android) records the video and Audio and then encodes raw pixels to h.264 and AAC using VideoToolBox and AudioToolBox, these encoded pixels are converted to PES (Packetized Elementary Stream) separately (Video & Audio). Now we are stuck at what to transfer to the server either PES or MPEG-TS, which one gives the minimum latency and packet loss like Periscope, Meerkat, Qik, UStream and other live streaming applications.

For transmitting which networking protocol is best suitable TCP/UDP.

And what is required at server to receive these packets. I know FFMPEG will trans-code and generates the segmented files(.ts) and .m3u8 file for HLS streaming, but do we need any pipe before FFMPEG layer?

Please give me some ideas in terms of which is best and what are pros and cons of each.

Thanks
Shiva.

Comment: This is a lot to cover for one question. Can you narrow your scope a bit?

Comment: Hi szatmary, thank you for the reply. I am totally confused/stuck at here : Is transmitting PES(Packetised Elementary Stream) better or MPEG-TS in Live Streaming from mobile (IOS) to server. What are pros and cons of each.

Comment: So, eventually you need to get the data in a format the client can consume. Whether you want that to happen on the broadcast device, or on the server, it makes no difference. So what is easier, putting this logic on the server, or on the broadcaster?

Comment: The client is going to have .m3u8 file, would like to do HLS. At server we are going to build components based on what client sends lets say if client is sending PES then at server we will have a pipe->FFMPEG (which will do multiplexing of Audio and Video and then trans-code it segments the stream into small .ts file and final .m3u8 file which we will distribute to client). If client is sending MPEG-TS then there is no need to multiplex directly FFMPEG will segments and distributes.